# how to servre static html file using MERN

Tags: html, node.js, autodesk-forge, mern

I am using React for the frontend and Express for backend. I want to serve a static html page which is in my server folder.On the frontend when button is clicked different apis at the backend works.I have used res.redirect to run the next api when previous api call is successful..

Below is the code example..

app.js

```
 app.post('/api/forge/datamanagement/bucket/upload/uploads/:filename', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.params.filename);
  console.log("Token",access_token)
  var fs = require('fs'); // Node.js File system for reading files
  fs.readFile(`./uploads/${req.params.filename}`, function (err, filecontent) {
    console.log(filecontent)
      Axios({
           method: 'PUT',
           maxContentLength: Infinity,
           maxBodyLength: Infinity,
           url: 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/' + 
           encodeURIComponent(bucketKey) + '/objects/' + 
           encodeURIComponent(req.params.filename),
           headers: {
                 Authorization: 'Bearer ' + access_token,
                 'Content-Disposition': req.params.filename,
                 'Content-Length': filecontent.length
                },
            data: filecontent
                 }).then(function (response) {
                      // Success
                       console.log(response);
                       console.log("IdUrn ====>>>>>>>"+ response.data.objectId)
                       var urn = response.data.objectId.toBase64();
                       console.log("In Response")
                       res.redirect('/api/forge/modelderivative/' + urn);
                     }).catch(function (error) {
                          // Failed
                            console.log(error.message);
     
                            res.send(error.messa);
                             });
                           });});
```

So the above route which is /api/forge/datamanagement/bucket/upload/uploads/:filename gets called when user clicks a button on the frontend.This route then redirects the control to the this route..

```
   /api/forge/modelderivative/' + urn
```

full code is below here for the above route.

```
      app.get('/api/forge/modelderivative/:urn', function (req, res) {
        console.log("urrrrn=>>>>>",req.params.urn)
        var urn = req.params.urn;
        var format_type = 'svf';
        var format_views = ['2d', '3d'];
            Axios({
                  method: 'POST',
                  url: 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job',
                  headers: {
                            'content-type': 'application/json',
                             Authorization: 'Bearer ' + access_token
                            },
                     data: JSON.stringify({
                           'input': {
                            'urn': urn
                              },
                            'output': {
                                  'formats': [
                                         {
                                           'type': format_type,
                                            'views': format_views
                                           }
                                             ]
                                         }
                                      })
                                }).then(function (response) {
                                  // Success
                                 console.log("Translated=============>>>",response);
                                 res.redirect('http://localhost:8080/viewer.html?urn=' + urn);
                                 }).catch(function (error) {
                                          // Failed
                                      console.log(error);
                                      res.send("Error at model derivate job");
                                      });});
```

The above route redirects to the viewer.html file is is a file in my server folder.I want to send the urn to the html file aswell.When is user this code the error occurs 404 . Not found....The parent of app.js and viewer.html is server folder.How can i achieve this to serve the html file as well as pass the Urn variable to html file.I have been stuck on this for a while..

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand why `viewer.html` is not part of your **front-end** served through port `3000` instead of keeping it as part of the other functionality running on port `8080`. Either way, there is a **server** part to it.

As pointed out in the comments of the [AutoDesk forge viewer Api integration issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68981499/autodesk-forge-viewer-api-integration-issue) thread, you must be providing the file content like `viewer.html` somehow. Are you using `app.use(express.static('public'));` or something like that?

The `http://localhost:8080/viewer.html` request has to be handled somewhere and provide the **html file** for the client.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.Issue has been solved, and yes I am sending the encoded urn to the viewer.html